# With js-ctypes detect other profile windows (Windows)

Tags: windows, firefox-addon, jsctypes

OS = Windows.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can figure out with js-ctypes what profile a firefox window is using?

I discovered that window class is different for each profile. And all windows in one profile uses all same class.

My final goal is to go through a single window of each different window class for firefox and make it run this script: `if (profileName == 'blah') { Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).focus() }`

Thanks

ps:
one idea i had was on startup of profile and on consequent window focuses, update a file with the window class, but i want to avoid using file because: 1) im already using ctypes to get the window class so might as well go all the way.

ps ps:
my final goal is to drop ctypes and have a file watcher but that is in progress [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958280). but anyways once thats done i can just make each profile watch a file and if it turns to "focus most recent win of profile = 'blah'" then boom focus it right away.

Comment: I had an idea that works ok. I get all windows and itterate through them and if class is `MozillaWindowEx` then I check shell to see if it had command line arguments on it. If it did and the profile name of "X" than this works. But problem is, what if profile is launched without command line arguments how can I identify what profile it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was a js-ctypes solution and is here:

[ask.m.o :: Have handle to window, how to identify profile (WinAPI)](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/987/have-handle-to-window-how-to-identify-profile-winapi/?answer=1016#post-id-1016)